# Which is best way to write a customize directive for insert a DOM after directive DOM in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I want write a 'vt-require' directive override 'required' directive so I can wride a code:

```
<input type="text" name="form.fullname" data-ng-model="fullname" data-vt-required/>
```

The html will be:

```
<input type="text" data-vt-required="" data-ng-model="fullname" name="fullname">
<div class="error-list">
    <span data-ng-show="form.fullname.$error.required">The field cannot empty</span>
</div>
```

Follow this instructions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile , I can write it. But I don't know what is safe way to write it?
Option 1, 2, 3 or 4 to write code add

```
<div class="error-list">
<span data-ng-show="form.fullname.$error.required">The field cannot empty</span>
</div>
```

--

```
var vtRequiredDirective = [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        compile: function (elm, attr) { 
            //[Option 1]
            return {
                pre: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
                    //[Option 2]
                },
                post: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
                    //[Option 3]
                }
            }
        },
        link : function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
                    //[Option 4]
                }
    };
}];
```

I hope it is understandable.

Thanks.

Comment: Option 3 and 4 are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go for Option 4 (doing it in the link function).

Also I would add a require for form, so you can get the form name dynamically opposed to relying on the form name being set in the name attribute.

E.g.

```
require: '^form',
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $formCtrl) {

    // $name will be the form name
    var fullyQualifiedName = $formCtrl.$name + "['" + $attrs.ngModel + "']";

    // create the expression to be used by the ng-show for the error span
    var isRequiredExpression = fullyQualifiedName + ".$error.required && (" + $formCtrl.$name + ".$submitted || !" + fullyQualifiedName + ".$pristine)";

    // etc
    ....
}
```

Comment: If choose option 4, I must call $complie to transforming the template DOM => if not, directive data-ng-show="form.fullname.$error.required", will not be compiled. So I wonder is it best way?

Comment: Correct. We have used a similar approach. 
It may also be worth looking into ngMessages (introduced in Angular 1.3 i believe) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

Answer (score 0):

That would be option 4.

> The compile function deals with transforming the template DOM. Since
>   most directives do not do template transformation, it is not used
>   often.

Maybe you could also replace the whole directive with a template:

```
<input-requierd name="fullname" />
```

Directive:

```
var inputRequiredDirective = function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace = true,
    scope: {
      name = '@'
    }
    template: '<input type="text" data-ng-model="{{name}}" name="{{name}}"><div class="error-list"><span data-ng-show="form.{{name}}.$error.required">The field cannot empty</span></div>'
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want combo other validation like maxlength, minlength... so I prefer attribute directive.

Comment: Do you want to have custom directives for maxlenght/minlength as well? Do you want to render always the same validation message for **required**? I think you should divide the content (validation messages) from the representation. For the messages i'd use `ngMessages` and then I'd make a directive to render a container for the validations message. you can just render the validation message box after the input field, but maybe you want to show dem as tooltip or popup or at the top of the page. - Then you can just change your directive.

Comment: Yes, I  will have custom directives for maxlenght/minlength as well. All error message span in div tag. After that, the animation in HTML depend on css. The developer don't need code more, just add vt-required, vt-minlengh=3... at input. All forms have same behavior in one app.